# How to add log to pallet's cargo.toml file to use log::info

Tags: kitties, substrate-kitties-chain, build

While doing the tutorial of "Build the Substrate Kitties Chain" there comes a section
https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/kitties/pt1/#write-the-create_kitty-dispatchable

In this there it says 'In order to use log::info, add this to your pallet's Cargo.toml file, using the matching version as Substrate upstream.'

So How to add log in cargo.toml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add log in pallets\kitties\src\cargo.toml  first go into cargo.toml file and in the [dependencies] section add:

`log = {version = "0.4.14", feature = ["derive"]}`

Just keep in mind version may change depending upon the updates. So change it accordingly. Currently on the date of writing this answer version is 0.4.14

Answer (score 1):

Use Substrate's built-in sp-tracing!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSipV1LLUzM

add sp-tracing in the pallet cargo file under dev dependencies:

```
sp-tracing = { version = "6.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.37" }
```

use it in your code

```
use frame_support::{log::{info, warn}, .. };
  info!("info num: {:?}", num);
  warn!("warn num: {:?}", num);
```

in your pallet/mock:

```
pub fn new_test_ext() -> sp_io::TestExternalities {
    sp_tracing::try_init_simple();// Add this line
    system::GenesisConfig::default().build_storage::<Test>().unwrap().into()
}
```

Run tests with "RUST_LOG=info "

```
$ RUST_LOG=info cargo test -p pallet-template it_
```

will run tests that starts with "it_"